# How do I specify the compiler to use when cross-compiling rustc?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, toolchain

When I compile `rustc`, there is a option in the configure script to specify other targets to the core libraries (`libcore`, `libstd`, etc), so for example:

```
./configure --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu,i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

will compile and install the `rustlibs` for both these architectures.

My problem is that this command will use my default gcc to compile everything, (since my system is multilib, it will successfully compile to i686 too), but what I want is to use my toolchain compiler instead, so for example:

I have 2 toolchains in my amd64 system: `i686-unknown-linux-gnu` and `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi`.

When I run configure with these parameters:

```
./configure --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu,i686-unknown-linux-gnu,arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
```

When compiling the `rustlibs`, I want the script to use x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-**gcc** for `x86_64`, and i686-unknown-linux-gnu-**gcc** for `i686` and arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-**gcc** for `arm`.

That way the `rustlib` will be compiled using the `glibc` and other libraries from the toolchain and not the default from my system. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's specified using suffixed environment variables: see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/ci/docker/cross/Dockerfile#L69) for what they do in CI.

Comment: This didn't work for me, what worked was creating the `config.toml` file with `[target.i686-unknown-linux-gnu]
cc = "i686-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc"
cxx = "i686-unknown-linux-gnu-g++"`